# How to register custom check-in policies in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, checkin-policy

In Visual Studio 2017, to register custom check-in policies we would use `privateregistry.bin` located in **%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15_...**, and we would add keys to the following path:

`\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_24405233Exp_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies`

In Visual Studio 2019, we did the same thing, and it doesn't load our custom check-in policies. Is anything changed here?

Answer (score 0):

The registry path `…\15.0_24405233Exp_Config\…` is specific to VS2017. For VS2019 it will be `16` something.

Comment: Of course we're registering it in 16. By `we did the same thing` I mean all things just changing versions accordingly.